# How to check the convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can we check the convergence of $$\sum_{n=0}\frac{n^3}{(f(x))^n}$$ when we know that $f'(x) >2$ and $f(x) /x>1$? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: In the denominator, you have $(f(x))^n$. By any chance, do you mean $(f(n))^n$? Otherwise, the series may certainly diverge or converge (take $f(x)=3x$, for example; converges for some $x$ and diverges for other $x$).

Comment: Do we use the quotient rule? @Clayton

Comment: I think it is meant x not n @Clayton

Comment: My example shows that it can do either, then. I don’t think there is anything else the can be said besides, “It may converge or diverge depending on $x$ and the function.”

Comment: Maybe the question wants a generic answer like $f(x)>1$, which is guaranteed for $x>1$, but it seems like a cheat to me for the answer to be something like this.